# Calculate p-value from non normal distribution

Tags: distributions, p-value

I calculate the probability of finding a value as extremum as alpha using this function (toy distribution):

```
2*(1-pnorm(abs(0), mean = 0, sd = 1))
```

But I'm not sure how to do this when the null distribution does not behave as a Gaussian distribution. I've tried something like `integrate(approxfun(neg.dis), lower=3, upper=7)` but I don't think this is the way to do this.

This is the density plot of my distribution, I'm only interested in one tail (the most negative).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper way to do it.

You need a cumulative density function (so the integral of `neg.dis`), and then use this to extract the p-value for the sample you have.

Comment: I though it so, but I'm confused as by puting `integrate(approxfun(neg.dis), lower=-4, upper= -1.2)` I get an area of `1.000637 with absolute error < 0.00011` bigger than 1. And I'm not sure how to calculate the lowest bounds I can use (lower and upper) without getting the error message Error in integrate(approxfun(neg.dis), lower = -3.4, upper = -1.1) : 
  non-finite function value

Comment: As it's an approximation, it's "normal" to get numerical differences. The bounds should be the bounds of `neg.dis` (I don't know the language you are using, not familiar with this), inside, you can get an approximation, outside, it's basically 0 (lower) or 1 (higher).

Comment: I'm confused  because of thinks like this `1 - integrate(approxfun(neg.dis), lower=-4.5, upper=max(neg.dis$x))$value` then I get  -0.0009573024 as the area calculated is bigger than 1. Tha's why I'm not fully sure this is the ok way to calculate the probability, or it's just that I need more values to get my null distribution.

Comment: Well, depends on what's the question you are asking, but integrateion or 1-integration is the same. With more points, you would get less numerical noise indeed.